# create associative array with key and value generated in for

Tags: laravel, for-loop, laravel-5, eloquent

i´m traying to create associative array, from query in laravel.

```
public function assignAllCall(Request $request)
    {
        $callList = [];
        $newCall = [];

        for($i=0; $i<count($request->get('calls')); $i++){
            array_push($callList, Listado::where('id', $request->get('calls')[$i])->get());
        }

        for($i=0; $i<count($callList); $i++){
            for($j=$i; $j<count($callList[$i]); $j++){
                $newCall = [
                    'nomape'            => $callList[$i][$j]->nomape,
                    'direccion'         => $callList[$i][$j]->direccion,
                    'provincia'         => $callList[$i][$j]->provincia,
                    'ciudad'            => $callList[$i][$j]->ciudad,
                    'cp'                => $callList[$i][$j]->cp,
                    'telefono'          => $callList[$i][$j]->telefono,
                    'movil'             => $callList[$i][$j]->movil,
                    'id_teleoperadora'  => $request->get('teleoperadora'),
                    'id_estado'         => 1,
                    'fecha_asignacion'  => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:m:s'),
                    'created_at'        => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:m:s'),
                ];
                
            }

            print_r($newCall);
            // create call
            //$result = Llamada::create($newCall);
        }  

        //return $result;
    }
```

i have this function that receive param from ajax and this values it´s ids array.

I need get all data from this ids for get all data and create new calls with this data, for this i have one for to do query and assign to array. after i´m traying to create associative array but when i do `print_r` always i return same result:

```
Array
(
    [nomape] => x
    [direccion] => x
    [provincia] => x
    [ciudad] => x
    [cp] => x
    [telefono] => x
    [movil] => x
    [id_teleoperadora] => x
    [id_estado] => x
    [fecha_asignacion] => x
    [created_at] => x
)
```

always same value. I don´t know if i do well my function or have one better solution for to do this.

Thanks for read and thanks for help.

Comment: If I am correct you want to store all values in $newCall, then instead of `$newCall = [ ` it should be `$newCall[] = [` to add a new column for each loop entry, also you are saving all the iterations of inner loop to same index of $newCall for $j

Comment: Is `$request->get('calls')` a array? If it is then you should use `whereIn()` and `map()`. It should help you get the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
            for($j=$i; $j<count($callList[$i]); $j++){
```

try this:

```
            for($j=0; $j<count($callList[$i]); $j++){
```